# How do I configure the built-in Postfix on Mac OS X to not connect directly to destination hosts other than itself?

Tags: macos, mac, smtp, tunnel, postfix

I run cron jobs on my Mac laptop, and so I want the mail daemon to be able to send the output mail to my regular mail account. I've got that working (my local account has a `.forward` file), but I'm often on networks where connecting to the destination's MX on port 25 doesn't succeed.

Therefore, I would like to have the local mail daemon send its outgoing mail, regardless of the destination, to another SMTP server (which happens to be a SSH port-forward to a server under my control). How do I configure the Apple-supplied Postfix to do this?

Update:

I tried setting  `relayhost = [localhost]:40125` (where 40125 is the SSH port forward), but while I can now send mail to a proper Internet mail address (e.g. `kpreid@switchb.org`), cron job mail (which is addressed to `kpreid@<whatever the DHCP hostname is>`) doesn't get delivered. From the one bounce I saw, it appears that this causes *all* mail, even for the local hostname, to go to the relayhost first.

Therefore, I need a way to relay to `[localhost]:40125` *unless* the address domain is this machine's domain (which varies frequently).

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `relayhost` directive in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` (and maybe tweak some other settings, but that's hard to say without knowing the default config from Apple).

Comment: It worked; no additional configuration was needed. I added `relayhost = [localhost]:40125`, where 40125 is the SSH port forward (`-L localhost:40125:localhost:25`); according to the comments in the file, the square brackets specify to connect directly rather than looking up a MX for the domain (which might be unnecessary for localhost, but hey).

Comment: Unfortunately, while this works for general outgoing mail, this seems to cause cron-job mail to fail because it's trying to send to "`<account>@<whatever my DHCP-generated hostname is>`" via the relayhost (at least, I received one bounce for this), rather than first finding the `.forward` in the local account. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose the `mydestination` setting isn't correct then, or maybe one of the other my* settings.  You can find an explanation of all available settings in `man 5 postconf`.  Also, on Ubuntu (I'm not sure if Mac OS X uses "Vixie cron" too?) it's possible to tell cron who to mail by setting a MAILTO environment variable in crontab (see `man 5 crontab`).